# substracting list of tuples from another list of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I have two lists of tuples but imagine long lists of tuples and the idea is to get these two conditions

> 1. tuples that are only in list2
> 2. get rid off of individul tuples where the first element of tuples in list1 match the first element tuples in list2

```
list1 = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (3,4), (2,6)]
list2 = [(1,2), (1,3)]
```

expected output

```
result = [(3, 4), (2,6)]
```

I tried this approach but it results in duplicates

```
[x for x in list1 for y in list2 if x[1] != y[1]]
```

this also gets rid of `(1,5)` but it's not working

```
[x for x in list1 if x in list2 and x[0] != list2[0]]
```

this approach with duplicates

```
l = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x not in list2 and x[0] != y[0]:
            l.append(x)

[(3, 5), (3, 5), (5, 8), (5, 8)] # I want without duplicates
```

Comment: I edited it and there's also an exected output to consider bcause at the end i'd like to get [(1,2), (1,3),(3,4), (2,6)]

Comment: no, because I'd like to combine list2 + result at the end, 
 I'll add another approach I've tried but the problem is that I get result only with duplicates

Comment: @learner_from_scratch, do make your expected result to be unambiguous to avoid confusion

Comment: I did that but can you help with duplicates approach i'd just added

Comment: can you check the edited question and the added approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect *"first element of tuples in list1"* and combine 2 conditions for a single list comprehension:

```
list2_x0 = [t[0] for t in list2]
res = [t for t in list1 if t in list2 or t[0] not in list2_x0]
```

---

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (2, 6)]
```

Comment: thank you, is there another way to combine two list of tuples together? I tried your solution for this list2 = [(2, 3), (2, 4)]
list1 = [(0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 5), (0, 5), (1, 5), (4, 5)] it didn't work

Comment: @learner_from_scratch, "combine" for the 1st condition?

Comment: yes combine two lists of tuples in case, tuples that are only in list2 and tuples in list1 without tuples that aren't in list2 according to the first element in list2

Comment: "are only in list2" and " that aren't in list2" - that's a complete contradiction

Comment: I meant tuples that aren't in list2 according to the first element in tuples in list2

Comment: in general, is there a way to combine two lists of tuples without duplicates, does this work list3 = list1 + list2? how can I correct my last added approach?

Comment: @learner_from_scratch, your approach is less effective: it traverses `list2` for each item of `list1`. If `list2` would have a bigger size your approach will be tremendously ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your list to numpy arrays, you can solve this issue with numpy functions.

```
list1 = np.array([(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (3,4), (2,6)])
list2 = np.array([(1,2), (1,3)])
todelete=np.isin(list1[:,0],list2[:,0])
difference=np.delete(list1,todelete,0)
```

---

```
[[3 4]
 [2 6]]
```